# Code Signing Identity does not match in my keychain, for mac app store developing?

Tags: xcode, sign

1, I already download the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority",and add it into my keychain.

2, My team leader already had created two Cers for Mac App store developing, I download and add it into my keychain.

3, I used two methods to sign my add, but failed all.

First, add code sign section in my .xcodeproj(3.2.5).

Second, I used script:

```
productbuild --component ./bin/MAS_Release/MyApp.app /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: My Company Co., Ltd." --product ./src/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist MyApp.pkg
```

But it failed with information:
    Code Signing Identity '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: My Company Co., Ltd.' does not match any valid, non-expired, code-signing certificate in your keychain.

I observed that my certifications in keychain don't have small trangle.

how make the small trangle absence?(when I'am importing the Cers from my Agent, it don't have the trangle absence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were trying to code sign app on the machine that is not the one generated CSR request. You need export and import the private key also from original mac's keychain to the current mac.